# XSLT - Match and group times

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-2.0, transformation

I'm trying to create some time schedules based on the XML below. This is mock data so ignore the massive gaps in time. Essentially when the day code matches a 0 as seen below, I need to pull all the values ONLY after midnight (00:00) and discard the rest and increment the day + 1. However, if the in and out times overlap on midnight, such as 1755-0115 in the example below, then I still need to grab the in time as the same day on the file, but hard code the 1755 as 00:01 and still increment by one day. Everything else before midnight is still discarded. All blocks are always going to be in order and the earliest punches (such as 0900) are morning punches.

```
`<Employee>
      <employee_id>123456</employee_id>
      <day_code>0</day_code>
      <day>12-01-18</day>
      <block>
         <in>0900</in>
         <out>1526</out>
      </block>
      <block>
         <in>1526</in>
         <out>1526</out>
      </block>
      <block>
         <in>1526</in>
         <out>1740</out>
      </block>
      <block>
         <in>1740</in>
         <out>1755</out>
      </block>
      <block>
         <in>1755</in>
         <out>0115</out>
      </block>
   <block>
      <in>0115</in>
      <out>0315</out>
   </block>
   </Employee>`
```

So I need it to look like this when I pull the data out.

```
'<Employee_Schedules>
         <in>12-02-18-T00:01</in>
         <out>12-02-18-T01:15</out>
   <block>
      <in>12-02-18-T01:15</in>
      <out>12-02-18-T03:15</out>
   </block>
   </Employee_Schedules>`
```

I was thinking of checking two blocks using the preceding sibling function. Check if the first block's in time entry is less than the second block's out time entry, with a second conditional to check the immediate that the immediate block's in time is less than the out time, but that wasn't working too well.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the date and/or time format the XSLT/XPath 2 and later respectively XSD date and time format or is that as awful as in the sample data? As for the time values, how does one decide whether e.g. 0900 is before or after midnight?

Comment: Its just sample data and all need to be XSLT/xpath 2 format. And to your second question ... that's the issue I'm running into. That's why I was thinking of using 'preceding-sibling' to compare the entries in the two blocks to find out if it was morning vs after midnight.

Comment: So can we assume the first `block` child is always before midnight and we can identify the first after midnight be selecting the first following sibling `block` with a time less than or equal to the one in the first `block`?

Comment: Yes, your assumptions are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I "fixed" the format of `day_code` to use the XSD/XPath `yyyy-mm-dd` and then simply wrote two templates comparing `in` or `out` values to the ones in the first `block` child:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:template match="Employee[day_code = 0]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Employee[day_code = 0]/block[position() gt 1 and in > ../block[1]/in and out &lt;= ../block[1]/in]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:variable name="date" as="xs:date" select="xs:date(../day)"/>
          <xsl:variable name="new-date" as="xs:date" select="$date + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
          <in>
              <xsl:value-of select="dateTime($new-date, xs:time('00:01:00'))"/>
          </in>
          <out>
              <xsl:value-of select="dateTime($new-date, xs:time(replace(out, '([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})', '$1:$2:00')))"/>
          </out>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Employee[day_code = 0]/block[position() gt 1 and in &lt;= ../block[1]/in]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:variable name="date" as="xs:date" select="xs:date(../day)"/>
          <xsl:variable name="new-date" as="xs:date" select="$date + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
          <in>
              <xsl:value-of select="dateTime($new-date, xs:time(replace(in, '([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})', '$1:$2:00')))"/>
          </in>
          <out>
              <xsl:value-of select="dateTime($new-date, xs:time(replace(out, '([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})', '$1:$2:00')))"/>
          </out>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq5Z gives the result

```
<Employee>
   <block>
      <in>2018-12-02T00:01:00</in>
      <out>2018-12-02T01:15:00</out>
   </block>
   <block>
      <in>2018-12-02T01:15:00</in>
      <out>2018-12-02T03:15:00</out>
   </block>
</Employee>
```

Note sure what is supposed to happen if the first block element does have the change e.g. has `<in>0900</in>` but `<out>0700</out>`.

Example is XSLT 3 but the use of the `xsl:mode` declaration could be rewritten in XSLT 2 by using

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```